# IEnumerable<> to ObjectSet<>, reason: INCLUDE

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, ienumerable

I am working on MVC3 app, using Entity Framework 4.1. I did LINQ query, and returned it as `IEnumerable<T>`. But, in controller, I have to use `Include(other entity)`, like in `ObjectSet`, so I can show in view other entity values (which is associated to the one I am doing query on). I tried explicit cast from `IEnumerable<T>` to `ObjectSet<T>`, but it throws exception. Is there any way I can get `ObjectSet` from `IEnumerable`, or to include entity in `IEnumerable`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your context is still alive (if you haven't left the using) and if you haven't done `.ToList()` you should be able to cast to `ObjectQuery<T>`.

A safer practice would be to use an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` which checks if queryable is a `ObjectQuery<T>` and if so casts to `ObjectQuery<T>` and returns result .Include() otherwise returns the input query.

Comment: Expanding on this, you could return is there a particular reason you're using IEnumerable?  If you returned IQueryable to your controller, it can use the IQueryable Include

Comment: If I use IQueryable, I get "The entity or complex type  cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Answer (score 0):

Once you have it cast to an IEnumerable, it becomes disconnected from the datasource.

You should include the related entities in the DAL while it is still an IQueryable or IObjectQuery and then return the complete result as an IEnumerable.

Otherwise, you will be doing an extra hit on the DB.

Si

Comment: Do you see the entities being populated before they leave the Dal, are they being lost on the transfer to the controller?

Comment: When I use query directly on ObjectSet, it works even without include, I'm getting all fields. But when I use query on query I mentioned in last sentence, it doesn't. It's lost when I use query on IEnumerable (as result of query)...

Comment: I wouldn't try using the include on the IEnumerable, but rather in the source on the object set and return the entity ready for use.  If you need access to other properties of the entity (such as navigation properties) perhaps it might be more prudent to put those into their own function with their own views to manage the view complexity etc.